# Sending an Azure blob as an attachment from Azure

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to send a blob file from an Azure container as an attachment in an email generated from a Runbook powershell script.  Is there actually a way to do this without first downloading that blob file to a local drive? I wanted to do it 100% on Azure.   It seems that 'Get-AzureStorageBlobContent' will only download to a local directory.  Is there a way to this at all while remaining on the cloud.

$att is the csv file here:

```
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $att -Container $Container -Context 
$StorageContext  -Force


$a = Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $Container -Blob "filename.csv" 
-Context $StorageContext 
$attachment = $a.Name

---
 $msg.Attachments.Add($att)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is physically adding a blob as an attachment, then the blob has to be downloaded to wherever that code is running. Note: if this is all taking place within Azure, and in the same region, there are no bandwidth egress charges.

If you are just providing a *link* to a blob, then there's no downloading that takes place. You'll just want to think about public vs private links (if it's private, you'll need to generate a SAS URL).

Comment: Yes this is all taking place on the cloud.   I want to email the actual CSV file. How do I pass that to the smtp.Attachments.Add() method?   When I pass the file in it gives me a Cannot execute a method on a Null object error.   Is there a way to email the actual file? 100% in the cloud.

Comment: Could you please add your code snippet into question? It could be better to resolve the issue.